# Flutter: Running multiple UI tests from different files

Tags: flutter, ui-testing

Is there a way to run multiple **UI tests** in Flutter when the tests are in different files.
Currently, when one wants to run a test that is called differently than `main_test.dart` then `target` parameter is used:

`flutter drive --target=./test_driver/feature_one_test.dart`

Is there a way all the tests that are in given folder? e.g.:

`flutter drive --target=./test_driver/*`

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing that question, there was no easy way to run multiple files nicely.

That's why I've created [a package](https://pub.dev/packages/fast_flutter_driver) that was able to do achieve that.